# Bash output Regex for no-space string and slashes

Tags: regex, bash, unicode, sed

This should be a pretty simple question with a relatively simple answer.

I'm trying to use regex to parse an output to be slightly modified.

I have this bit of bash code as a variable in a script currently:

```
 $(/usr/bin/csvstat /home/icgwfrpa/Scripts/test.csv | sed -r 's/,/;/g' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g')
```

This variable is returned as:

```
1. date     <type 'datetime.datetime'>  Nulls: False    Min: 2017-06-26 18:00:01 Max: 2017-07-14 12:00:01   Unique values: 425  
2. diskusage1   <type 'int'>    Nulls: False    Values: 26; 27; 28; 29   
3. partition1   <type 'unicode'>    Nulls: False    Values: /dev/mapper/rootvg-lv_root   
4. diskusage2   <type 'int'>    Nulls: False    Values: 30   
5. partition2   <type 'unicode'>    Nulls: False    Values: /dev/sda1  Row count: 425
```

which is great.

I am now looking to strip everything now from this variable except for strings like `/dev/mapper/rootvg-lv_root` or `/dev/sda1` (or anything else similar that starts with `/dev/*` if it shows up in this output). I'm not sure how escape characters work in regex with slashes so help would be appreciated.

To clarify, my desired output should just be the string starting /dev/... up to the space, followed by a space or comma, followed by the next string found in the sequence.
Thanks. Sorry if my question wasn't written well.

Comment: `pretty simple question with a relatively simple answer` so probably already aksed and answered thousands times. What have you tried so far?

Comment: try this : \/dev(.*)\s

Comment: This is easy to answer with proper input and desired output. It is not clear in your given Input, if a path always ends with a dot, space or something.

Comment: And even if you have a reason to enclose your cmd in `$(...)` (like var=$(cmd...)`), it is distracting to your Q to include it. Keep it simple and **edit your Q** to show us your sample input that creates your required sample output. Good Louck.

Comment: If you know sed well enough to write `':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'` then you shouldn't need to ask this question. I suspect the reality is you got that script from someone else, have no idea how it does whatever it is it's doing nor how to enhance it to your needs now so why are you using it? Whatever it's doing there's a far simpler, clearer awk script could do the same and you'd be able to enhance it yourself so maybe ask for help with that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `/dev/` paths only appear once in a line...

```
$sed -r '/dev/!d;s#^.*(/dev/[^ ]*)\b.*#\1#' dev.txt
/dev/mapper/rootvg-lv_root
/dev/sda1
```

- `/dev/!d` - delete lines without `dev`
- `s#^.*(/dev/[^ ]*)\b.*#\1#` use `s###` rather than `s///` with `/dev/[^ ]*` (/dev/ followed by non-space characters, then `\b` a word boundary.  Replace with `\1`, the first capture group.
- use `sed -r` or `sed -E` to allow capture group parens to be unescaped.

Comment: It's sed, not awk.  And yeah, most shells don't need bang escaped.  Fixed.